# Java Error: method searchElement in class ConstructAVLTree cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, loops, class, methods, android-activity

```
class ConstructAVLTree{
    private Node rootNode;
    public ConstructAVLTree(){
        rootNode = null;
    }
private boolean searchElement(int element){
    return searchElement(rootNode, element);
}

private boolean searchElement(Node head, int element){
    boolean check = false;
    while((head != null) && !check){
        int headElement = head.element;
        if (element < headElement){
            head = head.leftChild;
        }
        else if (element > headElement){
            head = head.rightChild;
        }
        else{
            check = true;
            break;
        }
        check = searchElement(head, element);
    }
    return check;
}
}

public class AVLTreeExample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        ConstructAVLTree obj = new ConstructAVLTree();
        char choice;
int ch = sc.nextInt();
        switch(ch){
case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter integer element to search: ");
                System.out.println(obj.searchElement(sc.nextInt()));
                break;
```

**I am making a program that can add, remove elements (stacks and queues-like) and display elements in pre, in and post-order traversal. I tried changing boolean to void and default but didn't work and had more errors than expected. Hopefully someone can help me with this error, thank you.**